# starting smoothdivscroll at random position

Tags: jquery-plugins, random, smooth-scrolling

I am using smoothdivscroll plugins. I want to start scrolling at different position f text when page is reloaded or refreshed. How can I do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to write some code yourself for this special function. SmoothDivScroll has an option, **startAtElementId**, that you can use to tell the scroller to start at the position of a certain element (id). If you are loading the content of the scroller dynamically on the server side (using PHP, ASP.NET or something similar) you could make the server side code pick one of the content elements and add a certain id to it. Then you would set the option like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({ 
         startAtElementId: "yourID"
      });
   });
</script>
```

You could also use the method **jumpToElement**. First you would initialize the plugin. Then directly after you would make a call to jumpToElement and tell it to jump to an element with a random number between 1 and the total number of elements you have loaded. This is not tested in any way, but I think it would look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {
      // Initialize the plugin
      $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll();

      // Randomize an element
      var numberOfElements = $("#scrollableArea *").length;
      var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * numberOfElements + 1 );
      $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll("jumpToElement", "number", randomNumber);

   });
</script>
```

As I said, the above code has not been tested, but something along those lines should work.

Good luck!